# weighted central tendency in python

Tags: python, average

I have a list, like the one below:

```
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10]
```

I want to calculate the list average, however, arithmetic mean would not be an answer. I want my result to be skewed toward `10` because it is assumed to have much more weight. Geometric mean is not also an option. I wanted to know if there are other measures of central tendency that can be calculated in python using predefined functions. I am preparing my data for a neural network and I shall use various weights to see which one performs better. That is why I am looking for predefined functions so I can change their parameters to create multiple databases for my Neural Network.

Thanks in advance

P.s. The priority is to find the measure. Applying it in python comes next.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [math.se] or [datascience.se] since it's a question about the measure and not the programming (but be sure to check out their on-topic pages first)

Comment: If I had 9 measurements with a value of 1 and only 1 measurement with a value of 10. I would seriously think about the presence of outliers. I am not exactly sure why you would want to weight the average towards the outlier. However, it does depend on what you are measuring and whether this variation is expected or not.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks for the hint. My bad! I will definitely look it up there.

Comment: @ScottC Thanks. But there are not any outliers. Actually the value of `10` is my main data. Others are side dish!

Comment: The math and Python are easy. What matters is deciding how to weight your data and only you can know that since it depends on the underlying significance. Plucking a weighting algorithm out of the air seems arbitrary and rather meaningless.

Comment: @user19077881 You are absolutely right. I am not looking for any arbitrary algorithm. Actually, I am looking forward to see if a pre-defined algorithm matches my data; or more precisely, extracting the underlying nature of my data, if it follows an specific function.

Answer (score 2):

From my deep learning practice I don't quite agree that a higher weight should be desired.

Yet regarding your particular question, you can solve it
with straightforward power. High values become much larger, lower values much lower. After computing mean of powered values, compute a respective root, to return to the old scale.

And make sure you use an odd value for power, so that negative numbers retain sign.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10])
power = 15
powered_mean = np.mean(np.power(x, power))
central_tendency = np.power(powered_mean, 1/power) # root
```

> 8.576958985908947

Comment: Thank you very much. This might be a useful solution. I just have to figure out the value of `power`.